# Is it possible, I don't have password for my wallet?

Tags: myetherwallet, password

I converted some BTC to my ether mist wallet early this year.

I did it before Mist was fully synced. I have a old macbook, so I still can't have it fully sync until now.

On Etherscan, I can see my Ether there. This week I decided to [use myetherwallet.com](http://www.myetherwallet.com) to transfer my ether to my other wallet.

I have the keystore file, was asked for my password. From my memory, I didn't type in any password in Mist. 
My question is: *Is it possible, I don't have password for my wallet? or I just forgot I did enter the password at the start?* Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes you definetly had to provide a password when you created your account with mist.

Your keystore file contain your private key, but it is encrypted, and you need your password to unencrypt it. You can try to  brute force your password with this tool:

https://github.com/burjorjee/pyethrecover

Comment: Thanks Julien! I clicked into the link, but have no idea how to start. Do I have to install any software to do it?

Answer (score 0):

As Julien mentioned you can use pyethrecover to attempt to brute force decrypt your password.  However, before you get to that point you should pull together a list of your best password guesses and try them systematically.  [This article](https://cryptoassetrecovery.com/2018/02/09/how-to-recover-your-lost-myetherwallet-mew-password/) has a good section on where to get password ideas, titled "How to Find the Correct Password"